# Can't connect to local MySQL server error on Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework

My website uses Magento and is hosted on Godaddy. It was working fine till yesterday but today, it is showing the following error :

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Trace:
#0 /home/greenveggy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/greenveggy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/greenveggy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/greenveggy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/greenveggy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',    Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/greenveggy/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

How do i resolve this ?

Comment: Have you contacted the support on Godaddy? Its usually some configuration they may have changed. Specially if it was working before.

Comment: get in touch with GoDaddy Tech Support, to get it rectified

Comment: Yeah,they replied that they have run all the tests and everything is fine from their side.

Comment: _have run all the tests and everything is fine_ Probably restarted MySQL, is the site still down with this error? Not finding the socket typically means that the MySQL server process has died.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tool n98-magerun.phar ([link](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)) with task sys:check to test yout db-connection

- you have to copy the file to path /home/greenveggy/public_html/ and make it executable
- then cd to this path and execute ./n98-magerun.phar sys:check

if the connection fails check your properties in /home/greenveggy/public_html/app/etc/local.xml

Comment: the magento root-path ( /home/greenveggy/public_html/ )

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the "check" button for the Database solved the problem. Site is functional again. Can anyone explain what just happened?